# Syntax error when adding if-else statement under a certain class in pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

Since it is advised against to have a string be your primary key, I have changed it to an integer and I wanted to set the number 1 equal to circle, the number 2 equal to square and the number 3 equal to triangle(and anything else will say undefined shape) I have tried adding this if else statement under my shape class and it gives me back a syntax error at the first line of that if statement.

```
class Shape(db.Model):
    if shape_name == 1
      print("Circle")
      if shape_name == 2
        print("Square")
        if shape_name == 3
            print("Triangle")
              else:
                print("Other Undefined Shape")
__tablename__ = "shape"

shape_name= db.Column((db.Integer), primary_key=True)
shape_size= db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
shape_colorname= db.Column(db.String(4096))
shape_color= db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget pythonanywhere. Just putting this code in the local Python interpreter will give quite a few errors.

There are quite a few things in your code that are incorrect:

- In Python, statements that create a code block (`if`, `else`, `while`, etc.) end in a colon;
- `shape_name` isn't defined where you are using it;
- It doesn't make sense (considering what you want to do) for you to keep increasing the indentation for the `if`;
- Don't put loose code inside a class definition, only other definitions (basically variables and functions); it should be either in a method or the constructor;

If I understand correctly what you want to do, here is a corrected version of your code:

```py
__tablename__ = "shape"

shape_name      = db.Column((db.Integer), primary_key=True)
shape_size      = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
shape_colorname = db.Column(db.String(4096))
shape_color     = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


class Shape(db.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        if shape_name == 1:
            print("Circle")
        elif shape_name == 2:
            print("Square")
        elif shape_name == 3:
            print("Triangle")
        else:
            print("Other Undefined Shape")
```

Make sure you understand what is going on in the code above.

As a personal recommendation, though, I would suggest you build a dictionary:

```py
class Shape():
    mapping = {
        1: "Circle",
        2: "Square",
        3: "Triangle"
    }

    def __init__(self, shape_name):
        print(self.mapping.get(shape_name, "Other Undefined Shape"))
```

Comment: This clarifies so much!! Thank you a ton. I do have one question in terms of continuing on with my program. I see that you recommended I build a dictionary but would this work if I wanted to create parameters as well? My goal is to create a program in which takes in pictures of shapes and outputs a guess of what that shape is. Would it be okay to add ranges within my dictionary or should that be done in the same way you added the if elif and else statements? Instead of it being called mapping I would name it something different and go from there. Thank you again

Comment: @Cherry I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand. When you say "create parameters," you want to create parameters for what? And as for "adding ranges," what do they range over?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify! as users submit photos of shapes, my goal is to have my code guess the shape. In order to do that, I need to define what these shapes look like. I will define for example a rectangle to have 90 degrees for all its angles. Then I will say that a rectangle has four sides and so on. By defining what a rectangle should look like in my python code, I will be able to have a program that takes in each picture submitted, checks if they meet that criteria, and then return the name of the shape. I was wondering if i can define this all within my dictionary or not.

Comment: @Cherry You'd have a few options. The best one would be to use ifs: `if cond0 and cond1 and ... and condN:` and chain it with elifs, one for each particular shape. Another one would be to indeed use a dictionary, with the keys being tuples, with each entry of the tuples representing the result of one particular inspection of the input shape - however, that is significantly harder to maintain, since you'd need to change all the keys if a new criteria is introduced.

Comment: Ahh I see! going in to change all the keys would indeed be harder so I will give your first suggestion a try. I truly appreciate all of your help!